# Is there a Rails Gem for the Microsoft Cognitive Services Image Search API - V5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bing, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I'm looking to use Bing's APIs to perform an image search. It seems the best image search option available is MSFT's Cognitive Services Image Search API - V5

https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f0ccf5ff8098cef3808/operations/571fab09dbe2d933e891028f

Is there a Rails Gem available to interact with this API so it's easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just want to point out that bing-search gem mentioned above is using the now deprecated Bing Search API, and not the current APIs under Microsoft Cognitive Services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bing-search](https://github.com/jonahb/bing-search) gem.

Comment: As mentioned by @Joseph Chee Chang bing-search gem uses the old Azure API.  As of yesterday (March 31, 2017) the Azure API is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

https://rubygems.org/gems/cognitivebing/versions/0.2.1 works with the new Cognitive API.